# How to create two circles of arcs moving by touch in Android

Tags: android, canvas, touch, automatic-ref-counting

can someone please give me advice or instruction how to create custom view, which draws two circles with different (or maybe same) count of arcs, and the most important, enable rotating each circle independently anti/clockwise by touch move? But no moving on center hole.

I think image describe it best
[rotating circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t92DY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I needed something like this and I can't find a component so I implement one.
A custom view that uses `Canvas` in `onDraw` method  .

For each wheel you can add a list of `String` to show in each section and a list of `Paint` to paint that section .

https://github.com/mehdi-azizi/Nested-Wheels-View/blob/master/NestedWheelApp/app/src/main/java/com/ma/nestedwheels/NestedWheelsView.java

[image]